# Is there effective way in laravel to select records from database and set them user_id?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have to make laravel application that use database 100k+ records. I have table with columns: `numer`, `date`, `segment`, `user_id`.

I am selecting records that I need with:

```
$datetime = new \DateTime();
$datetime->modify('+6 months');

$seg = "biz";

$select = DB::table('clients')
            ->where('user_id', $id)
            ->where('date','<',$datetime)
            ->where('segment',$seg)
            ->get();
```

I get some records and now, Is there anyway set `user_id` for like 100 of records from select?

Main rule is I cannot sort dates in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could **mass-update** the rows after selecting a given amount of rows to be updated:

```
$datetime = new \DateTime();
$datetime->modify('+6 months');

$seg = "biz";

$new_id = 743; // <-------- example of value to be updated

$updated_rows = DB::table('clients')
                  ->where('user_id', $id)
                  ->where('date','<', $datetime)
                  ->where('segment', $seg)
                  ->take(100)                       // <---- # records to be updated
                  ->update(['user_id' => $new_id]); // <---- new value(s) to update
```

Check [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#updates) related to this topic (it is oriented to Eloquent, but also applies for Laravel Query Builder).

PS: `$updated_rows` is the number of rows that has been updated.

Comment: Problem is I cannot update all rows, lets say there is 1000 records after select and i got 5 users, I wana choose user and pass him 100 records

Comment: @Gerv your case isn't very clear.. could you elaborate more? Provide an example to your desired output to be able to help you.

Comment: In application there will be 20 users. The job I have  to do is select from database all records that pass my select query and than set user_id for number of records I set in variable. So basicly i have to pass this query and update user_id for lets say for example 100 records.

Comment: @Gerv  I've updated my answer. Notice the previous line before the `->update([...])`.